# How can i group and restructure the JSON object in Angular8

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I am getting below response, I want to ReGroup all the data and its children based on `buSubRegion` which is present inside children now. And also needs to add `buSubRegion` outside children.

**For EX -** In below Response, `1UL Africa` belongs to **Africa object** and also present inside **Europe object**, so i need to merge children of all objects which belongs to `1UL Africa` into one array of object.

I want if buSubRegion have a same value and it is present inside many objects then find all those objects and merge into one.

Also, `Agbara - Savoury` dont have a **BU sub-region** So i don't want to include this object.

Can anyone please help me to achieve this.

```
const data = [
    {
      "name": "Africa",  
      "id":1,    
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Agbara - Laundry",
          "buSubRegion": "1UL Africa", 
          "children": [
            {
              'lineId':"R_D005_TPKDST02"
            }
        ]        
         
        },
        {
          "name": "Agbara - Savoury",         
          "children": [
            {
              "lineId":"R_D005_TPKDST02"
            }
        ] 
        }
      ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Europe",  
        "id":2,    
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Europe1",
            "buSubRegion": "1UL Africa",
            "children": [
                {
                  "lineId":"R_D005_TPKDST02"
                }
            ]            
          },
          {
            "name": "Europe2",
            "buSubRegion": "Test Europe",
            "children": [
                {
                  "lineId":"R_D005_TPKDST02"
                }
            ] 
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Latem", 
        "id":3,     
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "test1",
            "buSubRegion": "latem1",
            "children": [
                {
                  "lineId":"R_D005_TPKDST02"
                }
            ]           
          }
        ]
      }
  ];
```

**Below is my Expected Output**

```
[
    {      
      "buSubRegion": "1UL Africa", 
      "name": "Africa",
      "id":1,     
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Agbara - Laundry",
          "buSubRegion": "1UL Africa",
          "children": [
              {
                "lineId":"R_D005_TPKDST02"
              }
          ] 
        },       
        {
            "name": "Europe1",
            "buSubRegion": "1UL Africa",
            "children": [
                {
                  "lineId":"R_D005_TPKDST02"
                }
            ]            
        }      
      ]
    },
    {        
        "buSubRegion": "Test Europe",
        "name": "Europe", 
        "id":2,  
        "children": [         
          {
            "name": "Europe2",
            "buSubRegion": "Test Europe",
            "children": [
                {
                  "lineId":"R_D005_TPKDST02"
                }
            ] 
          }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Latem", 
        "buSubRegion": "latem1",
        "id":3,     
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "test1",
            "buSubRegion": "latem1",
            "children": [
                {
                  "lineId":"R_D005_TPKDST02"
                }
            ]            
          }
        ]
      }
  ];
```

Comment: can you share your code which you have tried

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `reduce` and inside that loop through children property to group the data by buSubRegion.

```js
const data = [{"name":"Africa","id":1,"children":[{"name":"Agbara - Laundry","buSubRegion":"1UL Africa","children":[{"lineId":"R_D005_TPKDST02"}]},{"name":"Agbara - Savoury","children":[{"lineId":"R_D005_TPKDST02"}]}]},{"name":"Europe","id":2,"children":[{"name":"Europe1","buSubRegion":"1UL Africa","children":[{"lineId":"R_D005_TPKDST02"}]},{"name":"Europe2","buSubRegion":"Test Europe","children":[{"lineId":"R_D005_TPKDST02"}]}]},{"name":"Latem","id":3,"children":[{"name":"test1","buSubRegion":"latem1","children":[{"lineId":"R_D005_TPKDST02"}]}]}];

const result = data.reduce((a,{children, ...rest})=>{
    children.forEach(({buSubRegion,...others})=>{
        if(buSubRegion){
            a[buSubRegion] ??= {buSubRegion, ...rest, children:[]};
            a[buSubRegion].children.push({buSubRegion, ...others})
        }
    });
    return a;
},{});
console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Comment: @Shilpa I'm not able to figure out the difference. can u update ur question.

Comment: @Shilpa use ||= instead of ??= & try

Comment: Your logic was perfect just issue with synatx and foreach i guess..Can you plz re modify ur code with normal forloop and proper typescript supporting synatx?